# php solve operation from string POST

Tags: php, string

I receice a string in POST.
The String contain an operation to solve like example: "34*5/2" or "56-4*3" or "5+4+6" ecc...the operation is always different from time to time
how can i solve the operation that i find in the string?
i do not want use the eval function

Comment: `eval($_POST['mystring']);`

Comment: @Daan: Yes, but it can be dangerous to do that.

Comment: i do not want use the eval

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17774360/variables-infix-to-prefix-to-postfix

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you need, all credits to http://www.website55.com/php-mysql/2010/04/how-to-calculate-strings-with-php.html

```
<?php
function calculate_string( $mathString )    {
    $mathString = trim($mathString);     // trim white spaces
    $mathString = ereg_replace ('[^0-9\+-\*\/\(\) ]', '', $mathString);    // remove any non-numbers chars; exception for math operators

    $compute = create_function("", "return (" . $mathString . ");" );
    return 0 + $compute();
}

$string = "34*5/2";
echo calculate_string($string);  // outputs 85
```

working example is here
https://eval.in/379103